# pycharm has no Qt platform plugin could be initialized error when using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, qt, matplotlib, pycharm, pyqt5

I installed my python as an independent program into my personal user folder on windows 10:

C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\

Then I installed all packages that I want from inside PyCharm 2021.2.3 community version via

File->Settings->Add package

It's been ok and I can run my numpy pandas data project etc. But when I add the matplotlib library and tried to do simple plot, it gave the `no Qt platform plugin could be initialized` error.

I searched for answers and proceed to install the following packages:

```
PyQt5
PyQt5-Qt5
PyQt5-sip
PyQt5-stubs
pyqt5-plugins
pyqt5-tools
qt5-applications
qt5-tools
```

Then I checked in these package's bin\ folders to ensure the 'platforms' folder exists and the qwindows.dll is present.

But matplotlib still fails with that no Qt platform error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that I have to put the PyQt5's lib path into my PATH environment variable like below:

First, go open the 'Edit Environment Variables for your account' dialog

Then, add the following 3 entries on **TOP** of the path list:

```
C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\bin
C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins
C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins\platforms
```

Also, if you have a variable named: QT_PLUGIN_PATH, you want to put this line at the **TOP** of the list:

```
C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins
```

After saving your environment variables, you need to restart PyCharm to have it "find" these libraries.

Well, this got me past this no Qt platform error in this case. But I have other python-qt programs that needs other python versions/install path, this will break those programs. I have found that pyqt programs usually have this problem, I still think (and sincerely hope) there is better approach than to mess with the PATH environment. I am still open to other suggestions of course.

Comment: Using pycharm *and* local python installation will always create problems if you need different versions and paths for each program.

Comment: @musicamante Could you provide an alternative that could have multiple python/PyQt versions coexist and functioning at the same time? I love using PyCharm, but if this is its fatal weakness, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use PyCharm.

Comment: @musicamante Then what do you use to allow multiple python/PyQt versions coexist?

Comment: My OS (gentoo/Linux) automatically installs multiple python versions without conflicts, and I only use one version for each major version of Qt/PyQt.