# How to resolve "no Qt Platform Plugin could be initialized" for a Qt5 application?

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5, anaconda3

I am working on a **python application based on PyQt5**. Everything was running good until I redo my PC and reinstall windows again because of some issue. I had copied my environment and after reinstalling **Anaconda**, I copied that environment again in **env folder**. Now the problem is that, when I run my code in **PyCharm IDE**, it displays and error dialog like this:

[image: This is the Error Dialog]

I have tried multiple solutions such as:

**Solution 1: Change the QT Files Location**

Sometimes, a simple trick such as changing the QT files location is enough to get rid of the error. Here’s how you can do it:

1. Launch File Explorer and open This PC.
2. Using the Search field, search for **pyqt5_tools**.
3. When Windows finishes the search, right-click the **pyqt5_tools** and head to Open folder location.
4. Head to **PyQt5 > Qt > bin**. Copy the **platforms** folder. <kbd>in my case bin is not available in this folder</kbd>
5. Make a new search for **site-packages** and open the folder.
6. There, paste the **platforms** folder.
7. Windows will warn you there’s already a folder with the same name. Click Replace the files in the destination.

**Solution 2: Run an SFC Scan**

There’s a chance Windows display the “Application failed because no QT platform plugin could be initialized” error due to corrupt system files. Fortunately, Windows has a built-in tool to help you fix the problem.

In the Start menu search bar, search for command prompt and select Run as administrator. Then, run the **sfc /scannow** command line. Windows will scan and automatically replace any corrupted system file.

[Solutions Reference](https://www.makeuseof.com/application-failed-no-qt-platform-initialized-error-fix/#:%7E:text=Sometimes%2C%20Windows%20display%20the%20%E2%80%9CApplication,can%20manually%20uninstall%20Windows%20updates.)

Nothing worked for me, I'm getting the same error all the time.
**How can I resolve the error displayed in the figure above?**

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Answer to this question

[Answer Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70896967/pycharm-has-no-qt-platform-plugin-could-be-initialized-error-when-using-matplotl)

To add PyQt5's library path to your PATH environment variable:

**1.** Open the **`Edit Environment Variables`** dialog.

**2.** Select the appropriate **`Path`** variable (either **User** or **System** variables).

(Note: I have changed in **`system variables`**)

**3.** Edit the variable and add the **`PyQt5`** library path as three entries at the top.

**4.** **Add the following 3 entries**, and make sure the entries are in the **desired order** and at the **top of path** variable.

**5.** Save the changes.

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ann_tool\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\bin
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ann_tool\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ann_tool\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins\platforms
```

**6.** Also, if you have a variable named: **`QT_PLUGIN_PATH`**, you want to put this line at the **top of the list**:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ann_tool\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins
```

(Note: In my case, Anaconda is installed for all users so, Anaconda will be found in **`C:\ProgramData`**)

**7.** Once you have saved the changes to your environment variables, it is necessary to **Restart PyCharm** in order for it to recognize and locate the updated libraries..

Comment: My envs folder is empty

Comment: locate to your environment and keep rest of the path as it is. @SanjayManohar

Answer (score 0):

For C++ just run windeployqt.exe for your exe, it will send all needed dlls (including platform dll) to your build directory

Comment: The question is targeting the Python and not the C++ programming language.